# Less than 180 phase shift in inverting amplifier

Tags: amplifier, bjt, phase-shift

I'm simulating (click [here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%203.125e-7%200.529449005047003%2050%205%2043%0At%20336%20192%20384%20192%200%201%20-3.1480872576021675%200.6795139006654898%20291%0Ar%20288%20128%20288%20192%200%2013400%0Ar%20288%20288%20288%20336%200%2010000%0Aw%20288%20128%20384%20128%200%0Aw%20288%20336%20384%20336%200%0Ar%20384%20128%20384%20176%200%20120%0Ar%20384%20256%20384%20336%200%20120%0Aw%20176%20336%20288%20336%200%0Ag%20176%20336%20176%20368%200%0Ac%20224%20192%20288%20192%200%200.000009999999999999999%20-3.768645090821013%0Ar%20208%20192%20160%20192%200%2050%0Av%20160%20288%20160%20336%200%201%2010000%200.002%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20176%20336%20160%20336%200%0Ac%20384%20176%20512%20176%200%200.0000010000000000000002%206.921214562169261%0Ar%20512%20176%20512%20256%200%201000%0Ag%20512%20256%20512%20272%200%0Ac%20432%20304%20432%20336%200%200.000001%203.091109658020242%0Aw%20384%20336%20432%20336%200%0Aw%20384%20256%20432%20256%200%0Aw%20288%20192%20288%20288%200%0Aw%20160%20192%20160%20288%200%0AR%20384%20128%20384%2064%200%200%2040%2010%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20384%20208%20384%20256%200%0Aw%20288%20192%20336%20192%200%0Aw%20208%20192%20224%20192%200%0Aw%20432%20256%20432%20304%200%0Ao%2014%202%200%204098%200.01953125%200.1%200%202%2024%200%0A)) a standard BJT - CE inverting amplifier.
However, as you can see in the plot, the phase shift between voltage at the resistor and signal voltage is very different from 180 degrees. I've heard that it has something to do with the delay due to RC group, however I wasn't able to better understand this effect and to calculate the real phase shift.

Could you help me?

[image]

Comment: Where are the two waveforms measured?

Answer (score 4):

Your capacitor at the emitter is too small. It causes tens of degrees phase lead. You have high hfe transistor, maybe it has very small internal BE junction resistance and the 50 Ohm at the base is seen less than 0,25 Ohm at the emitter. A perfect RC highpass filter affecting heavily at 10kHz.

Increase the cap at the emitter from 1uF to 250uF and see the difference.

ADD: It's a common error to calculate the RE bypass capacitor starting from the resistance of RE and the wanted -3dB frequency for the bypassing (see NOTE1). After doing it one wonders why the cap is clearly too small - just like you did.

Forming a proper equation (with complex phasors) for the base current shows that the cap at the emitter must be surprisingly big for low enough reactance. To make the highpass effect of the RE bypassing cap neglible, the reactance of the cap must be much smaller than Rx, where Rx is the parallel combination of RE and the resistance of the whole base circuit (=thevenin equivalent) divided by hfe (more exactly by hfe+1).

In your case the most remarkable component in Rx is 50Ohm/hfe.

NOTE1: It bypasses the RE, but it is still too high reactance in the base current circuit. For base current its effect is amplified by the transistor by factor hfe+1.

Comment: you're right, it works! however I don't fully understand the explanation.. in particular, I've been told that the highpass filter in the CE is related to the coupling capacitor, not the feedback bypass capacitor.. is it wrong? moreover, where did you get 0.25 Ohm? thanks again for the useful help!

Comment: @Surferonthefall The answer has more data

Comment: +1 If you think about the output impedance of an emitter-follower ...

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That's the case. RE bypassing capacitor must be able to load the emitter follower on its knees if one wants to  avoid the high pass slope type  gain reduction st the operating frequency